# In my WebView, a particular url is getting displayed. What is the problem?

Tags: android, webview

In my WebView, a particular url is not . Apart from this url, all urls are working. Please tell me what's the problem.

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.web_game);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://cobra-game.conversionlab.online/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to ignore the SSL errors as given below, You must be receiving some SSL errors while loading the URL.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d("Failure Url :" , failingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            Log.d("Ssl Error:",handler.toString() + "error:" +  error);
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And add this as well

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); this line helped showing the webpage but still few audio and video file are not supported. It comes as warning in logcat.

Comment: Enable Javascript for audio video support. 
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  @ShubhamAnand